# The truth value of $\exists\, y\geq 2\; \forall\, x\leq -1 \quad y\neq \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Determine the truth value of the following statement
$$P:"\exists\, y\geq 2\; \forall\, x\leq -1 \quad y\neq \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}"$$
negation of $P$ is :
$$\neg P:"\forall\, y\geq 2\; \exists\, x\leq -1 \quad y= \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}"$$
in order to know the truth of the $P$ I will investigate Its negation  which is,
$$\neg P:"\forall\, y\geq 2\; \exists\, x\leq -1 \quad y= \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}"$$
let $y\in[2,+\infty[$, and I will look if x exists on $]-\infty,-1[$ such that $y=\dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}$

let $f(x)=\dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}$ and I will use the variation of the function $f(x)= \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1}$.
[image]

$f$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on the interval $]-\infty,-1[$ and $y\in [2,+\infty[$ then by mean value theorem, We conclude that there exists at least one solution on $]-\infty,-1[$

**My questions:**

- Is my method correct?
- Is there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. Note that the equation $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}=2$ is equivalent to $2x-1=2x+2$, which has no solutions. Therefore, $\neg P$ is false, and so $P$ is true.

If the restriction of $y$ was that $y\in(2,\infty)$, then your method would be correct.

Comment: +1 I didn't pay attention to that thank you